# How do I prove the following fact about splitting fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

Hello I have the following problem:

> Let $F$ be a splitting field of the polynomial $g(X)\in k[X]$. If $E$ is another splitting field of $g$ then there exists an isomorphism $\psi:E\rightarrow F$ inducing the identity on $k$.

I somehow do not see why this should be true. So I mean I know that $g$ splits in $E,F$ and that $E=k(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$, $F=k(\beta_1,...\beta_m)$ where $\alpha_i, \beta_j$ are the roots of $g$ in $E$ respectivly $F$ right? But I don't know if $m=n$ do I? because if $m=n$ then I would define $\psi(\alpha_i)=\beta_i$ which is clearly an isomorphism but I'm not sure if this can be done.

Could someone help me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134318/discussion-on-question-by-wave-how-do-i-prove-the-following-fact-about-splitting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But I don't know if m=n do I?"

This is a degree argument. We may assume that $g(x)$ is monic. Then
$g(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i) = \prod_{j=1}^m (x-\beta_j)$ and so (by the definition when two polynomials are equal) $m=n$.

Comment: What if we are in the nonseperable case, and some of the roots are repeated?

Comment: @Wuestenfux So does my Idea hold if I use your proof that $m=n$ or is it still wrong?